how to detect user motion type in fitbit, like we have ActivitiyType in CoreMotion in watch os which gives motion type( stationary,walknig etc)
how can I detect user motion type in FitBit OS as we do in Watch OS using CoreMotion, I have some idea about using accelerometer 3 axis (x,y, and z) value to detect user motion type ( stationary, walking, running), However, I don't have the knowledge to use this value and make function which gives output as motion type based on these 3 values.
I have tried to use the Accelerometer sensor data form here:
https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/device-api/accelerometer/
I do not know how can I utilize these values to determine user motion or do I have to combine other sensor data with an accelerometer to detect user motion more accurately?
